# How to dislay data from SQLite3 using command line tool?

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, sqlite

I connected My java program to SQLite3 using jdbc.
Please tell me 
1. how can i retrive data from SQLite by using any command line tool?
2. Where the data is going means where are files related to database ?

Comment: Open up the command line tool, specifying your SQLite file as a parm.  Then issue SQLite commands.  Don't forget the closing `;` on a command.  Commands beginning with `.` are special commands to the tool.  See http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: Where this file will be created and how it can be used in java program.

Comment: You specify the file path as a parm on the command line.  You can create a new file or use an existing SQLite file.

Comment: Thanks for kind efforts. Tell me in this case  what will be url of jdbc connection string and where the file will placed.

Comment: You don't use a URL, and you place the file anywhere you want in the local file system.

Comment: everythiing is fine now... thxx